# Initiate a List taking character arrays, coming from a String array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I think it's easier to understand what i mean showing my code

```
        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        List<char[]> wordsInChars = new ArrayList<char[]>();
        for(String i: words){
            wordsInChars.add(i.toCharArray());
        }
```

so I create an array of Strings, taking the **text** variable as input, then i want to
pass it to the List without going through that loop. Is it possible to skip the for loop altogether?

I've tried

```
List<char[]> wordsInChars = Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(words).forEach(w -> w.toCharArray()));
```

Either way, which approach should be used? The code with the for loop works, but am not sure if just doing it all at declaration is just better.

edit: I actually managed with

```
List<char[]> wordsInChars = Arrays.stream(words).map(w -> w.toCharArray()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But feedback on which one of the two is better practice, is welcomed.

Comment: `Is it possible to skip the for loop altogether?`  Nope.  Even the stream equivalent still contains a loop, just one that's a little harder to see.

Comment: Also be careful as these are not equivalent.  `Arrays.asList` does not return an `ArrayList` (in fact it return an immutable list).

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is no. You are converting a `string[]` to a `List` and regardless of whether you will write the loop yourself or call some method that will do the loop for you, a loop is required to iterate over and convert these values. We can actually argue that multiple loops are necessary, as the `String.toCharArray()` method also iterates over each byte in the string in order to convert it to a `char` using the right encoding.
That being said, there is nothing wrong with having a loop in your code. Unless your code is being called very very frequently, you won't even notice the difference in execution time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different way, but it still has a loop internally so we haven't actually skipped the loop.

```
  String words = "This is some text I made.";
  List<char[]> s = Pattern.compile( "\\s+" ).splitAsStream( words ).map( String::toCharArray ).toList();
  for( char[] c : s ) 
     System.out.println( Arrays.toString( c ) );
```

Comment: `List<char[]> wordsInChars = Arrays.stream(words).map(w -> w.toCharArray()).collect(Collectors.toList()); `
worked for me, map completely escaped my mind somehow.

Comment: The difference is I didn't start with an array of Strings, I started with a whole string and split it into pieces and got the char[] in one line.

Comment: very true, i definitely like this approach.